# I have a problem that when I generate random grades for each of subject of each students in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that when I generate random grades for each of subject of each students, but I got the grades of all students are just the same (for each subject)
Here is my code.

```js
var java = {
  name: "Java",
  grade: 0
}

var python = {
  name: "Python",
  grade: 0
}
var arr = {
  name: "arr",
  Subjects: [java, python]
}

var arr1 = {
  name: "arr1",
  Subjects: [java, python]
}

var arrs = [arr, arr1]

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}

function gen(arrs) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      var ran = random(0, 10)
      arrs[i].Subjects[j].grade = ran

    }
  }
}

gen(arrs)
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrs))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy object exactly.
https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/

```js
var java = {
  name: "Java",
  grade: 0
}

var python = {
  name: "Python",
  grade: 0
}
var arr = {
  name: "arr",
  Subjects: [{...java}, {...python}] //<---------------
}

var arr1 = {
  name: "arr1",
  Subjects: [{...java}, {...python}] //<---------------
}

var arrs = [arr, arr1]

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}

function gen(arrs) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      var ran = random(0, 10)
      arrs[i].Subjects[j].grade = ran

    }
  }
}

gen(arrs)
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrs))
```

Comment: Thank you! But can I ask why Subjects = [java,python] is not right?. Sorry i am new to JavaScript

Comment: @NamNguyễn, this article is easier to understand.
https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/

Comment: @NamNguyễn, so does it help you?